# How to Update the Installed Widgets

Tags: jupyter-lab

When I started Jupyter Lab from the cmd prompt within a python virtual environment folder, I noticed the Jupyter startup process display that 
three of the Jupyter widgets are outdated.   There was no display message describing how to update these widgets.

Therefore, the question is:  How to update the Jupyter widgets?

I searched for a solution and did not find any.

The Startup code w/ three widget outdated messages at bottom

```
(ML3-2Gxa7Dh2) C:\pythonVE\ML3>jupyter lab

[I 11:26:05.773 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from c:\python37\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 11:26:05.773 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is c:\python37\share\jupyter\lab
[W 11:26:05.793 LabApp] Error loading server extension jupyterlab_latex
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 1572, in init_server_extensions
        mod = importlib.import_module(modulename)
      File "c:\python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyterlab_latex'
[W 11:26:05.840 LabApp] JupyterLab server extension not enabled, manually loading...
[I 11:26:05.881 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from c:\python37\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 11:26:05.881 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is c:\python37\share\jupyter\lab
[I 11:26:05.883 LabApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\pythonVE\ML3
[I 11:26:05.883 LabApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 11:26:05.883 LabApp] http://localhost:8888/
[I 11:26:05.884 LabApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[I 11:26:07.540 LabApp] 302 GET /lab (::1) 1.00ms
[I 11:26:16.232 LabApp] 302 POST /login?next=%2Flab (::1) 1.00ms
[W 11:26:47.607 LabApp] The extension "@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager" is outdated.

[W 11:26:47.609 LabApp] The extension "@jupyterlab/latex" is outdated.

[W 11:26:47.611 LabApp] The extension "@jupyterlab/toc" is outdated.

[I 11:26:48.411 LabApp] Build is up to date
|[I 11:26:54.426 LabApp] Kernel started: 5ba63189-6fa9-40cc-87ea-eea2d869
```

Widgets seem to work within the Jlab notebook.

Answer (score 24):

I had a similar problem which I could solve by typing the following command:

```
jupyter labextension update --all
```

With

```
jupyter labextension list
```

I could show me the extension including those that were outdated and the command to update them was shown there, too.

Since you're writing “cmd prompt” I expect you are using Windows, so maybe your results may vary. Because I'm unsing Linux and cannot test it on Windows, I don't know if npm behaves the same.

BTW: With

```
jupyter labextension --help
```

you can get further help on labextensions including the hint on “install” which might be interesting for you, too, because your output also complains about a missing LaTeX extension.